# shopify how to edit shopping cart

Tags: shopify

beginner to coding. I got shopify store. Need help with shopping cart. How can I edit shopping cart PHP files on server that for example not the title of the product "Brand New Adidas Sneakers" but the Item Number will be transferred to paypal as Title. I have basic plan.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking to do is not possible the way you want to do it as you cannot edit PHP on Shopify.

However, you can maybe use Liquid to pass the `line_item.product.id` or something of that sort to PayPal.  Documentation on [editing your cart](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/development/templates/cart-liquid).

You should also just be able to install the PayPal app to your store via the Shopify App Store.